# How to use custom base.yaml and python.yaml for rosdep

Tags: ros, ros2, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I point `rosdep` to custom files `rosdep/base.yaml` and `rosdep/python.yaml`?

I would like to test changes to the rosdep files before submitting a PR to the upstream repo or use my custom rosdep fork in a CI environment and not have to wait for my PR to be merged.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319299/how-to-use-custom-base.yaml-and-python.yaml-for-rosdep/) by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2019-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add a rule to the rosdep sources list with your custom rules: https://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/sources_list.html

You can use a `file://` url for local files for quick testing.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on 2019-03-24**:
Do you mean to change all links in the file `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list`? E.g. from `yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml` to `yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<your_user>/rosdistro/<your_branch>/rosdep/python.yaml`.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-03-24**:
You can insert instead of replacing. The first match is used. That will be easier to revert. And if you have a fork on GitHub that's the right sort of url.